# Two form in a same page

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms, fosuserbundle

Im using FOSUserBundle and im trying to integrate editing profile form and resetting passsword form into one page. But i failed ! is that possible ?

Can some one help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the both templates into one. Copy the forms below each other.
They will have separate controller action associated with their form action.

If you are saying that you want to have one form for both then it will be dificult as you have to call the corresponding function in one controller